# Can't retrieve data with pyodbc in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python.  I am trying to retrieve data from MYSQL using pyodbc, but I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.16.90;DATABASE=dababase_nameL;PWD=password')
cursor = con.cursor()

my_query = "SELECT OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FD_TRANDATA,"
"GBCLIENTE.FC_MATRICULA AS CD_CLIENTE"
"GBCLIENTE.FC_NOME AS NM_CLIENTE"
"OPTITULO.FC_NOMETITULO AS NM_ATIVO"
"OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FN_QTDEBANCADO AS QUANTIDADE"
"(OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FN_QTDEBANCADO * OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FN_PUOPER) AS VALOR_ATUAL"
"WHERE (OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FC_TPOPER IN('C-FINAL', 'V-FINAL')"

"FROM OPPOSICAO OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO"
"INNER JOIN OPTITULO ON OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FC_CODTITULO = OPTITULO.FC_CODTITULO"
"INNER JOIN OPPAPEL ON OPTITULO.FC_CODPAPEL = OPPAPEL.FC_CODPAPEL"
"INNER JOIN GBCLIENTE ON OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FC_MATRICULA = GBCLIENTE.FC_MATRICULA"
"LEFT OUTER JOIN GBCLIENTE E ON E.FC_MATRICULA = OPTITULO.FC_CODEMISSOR"

"AND (OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FN_QTDEBANCADO > 0)"
"AND OPPAPEL.FC_CUSTODIA  = 'CETIP'"
"AND (OPTITULO.FC_NOMETITULO  LIKE 'LC%' OR OPTITULO.FC_NOMETITULO LIKE 'CDB%');"

cursor.execute(my_query)

con.commit()
cursor.close()
data = pd.read_sql(my_query, con)
con.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-9f81c7fca238> in <module>()
     24 
     25 
---> 26 cursor.execute(my_query)
     27 
     28 con.commit()

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: Try printing your `my_query` to see what you are sending. You will notice that your variable has just the `SELECT OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FD_TRANDATA,` part of your query. Also, your `SELECT` statement is missing some commas, and you need a `WHERE` before using `AND` to filter your results.

Comment: Jon Koala, I printed the my_query sends only the first line:  SELECT OPHISPOSFECHAMENTO.FD_TRANDATA. How can I include the entire query in the my_query? Thanks

Comment: Raphy, you can easily just google the answer to that question (try _"python multiline string"_). It has actually been answered here at stackoverflow before.